# Using 'Type' and 'Enum' as parameters in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, types

I'm trying to writing a method that parses a string parameter into an enum. The enum's type is also determined by a parameter. This is what I've started with:

```
public static type GetValueOrEmpty(string text, Type type)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return (type)Enum.Parse(typeof(type)value);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Obviously this won't work for a number of reasons. Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: For a solution that includes nullabe enums and additional features check out https://gist.github.com/DoggettCK/1305566

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can make it generic instead, if you know the type at compile-time:

```
public static T GetValueOrEmpty<T>(string text)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return (T) Enum.Parse(typeof(T), text);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

If you don't know the type at compile-time, then having the method return that type won't be much use to you. You can make it return `object` of course:

```
public static object GetValueOrEmpty(string text, Type type)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return Enum.Parse(type, text);
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

If neither of these are useful to you, please give more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Should I upvote your answers anymore?  You probably don't even notice the +10 with your 86k of reputation.  ;)

Comment: @SarahVessels: your comment is so funny today.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a generic method. Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static TEnum ParseEnum<TEnum>(string s)
{
    return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), s);
}
```

EDIT: Fixed typo in code...

Comment: I like to add a 'where TEnum : struct' type constraint on these sorts of methods, to try and limit the types it can be called on (C# doesn't allow an 'enum' constraint, 'struct' is the next best thing...)