# How to use a variable for the type parameter of a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have been working on a mini ORM, it's just a really basic converter, and I have a few enums in my application. Think of gender in this application. I have this snippet now:

```
public T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
}
```

This works great. However, there is a catch. I need to hard-code which enum I want to have. If I want to dynamically switch to a different type, let's say Continent (an enum with 7 values), I have a problem, because I cannot know when the ORM reads which variable. Is there a solution for this?

A snippet of what I meant:

```
ParseEnum<Continent>(reader[idx].ToString());
```

I want to switch out "Continent" with a variable, for example property.PropertyType.

Comment: I don't know why so many people have posted the same question in the last few days. The answer is, "no, you can't do that".

Comment: @JohnSaunders is there a good duplicate target?

Comment: I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Perhaps there's a database final project due? It is getting close to the end of term.

Comment: Because it is easier to ask, than search.

Comment: [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has an overload that take a Type object as it's argument.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz OP alread uses it :)

Comment: Oh, Yes, what's the point of using generics then?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using 'Type' and 'Enum' as parameters in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255030/using-type-and-enum-as-parameters-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `ParseEnum` as non generic method and then let it be typecasted wherever in the code you are ready to type cast it to a the actual enum type. Note that enumType can be an fully qualified string and then you can create `System.Type` from that string at run time using `System.Type.GetType` method.

```
public object ParseEnum(Type enumType, string value)
{
    return Enum.Parse(enumType, value, true);
}
```

Comment: Worked for both of my enums. Thanks!